# Review star rating - prediction in R

Tags: r, rpart

I have a dataset of reviews that have the following structure:

```
{
"reviewerID": "XXXX",
"asin": "12345XXX",
"reviewerName": "Paul",
"helpful": [2, 5],
"reviewText": "Nice product, works as it should.",
"overall": 5.0,
"summary": "Nice product",
"unixReviewTime": 1152700000,
"reviewTime": "08 14, 2010"
}
```

I have got a bunch of reviews and would like to create a forecast based on the text of the review ("reviewText") using some text mining techniques.

I would like to train a classifier and then have an accuracy measure how well the system works. The rating of each review is given ("overall").

So far I did the following:

**Required packages (not all are required)**

```
library(plyr)
library(rjson)
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringi)
library(doSNOW)
library(tm)
library(NLP)
library(wordcloud)
library(SnowballC)
library(rpart)
```

The input data is available in JSON format:

[Sample Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eDRQ.png)

Out of this table reviewTexts are converted to a corpus.

**Create a corpus and apply some pre-processing steps**

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(tr.review.asin$reviewText))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
```

**Making a document term matrix**

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.999)
```

**Creating a training and test set**

```
dtmsparse <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(dtm))
train <- dtmsparse[1:6500,]
test <- dtmsparse[6501:7561,]
```

**Creating a model**

```
train$overall <- tr.review.asin[1:6500,]$overall
model <- rpart(overall ~., data = train, method= 'class')
mypred <- predict(model, newdata =test, type = 'class')
```

When I am plotting `obs_test` and `mypred` I am getting the following plot:

[Plot `obs_test` and `mypred`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlocx.jpg)

Unfortunately I don't have an idea if the last lines will guide me to a solution.

I would like to have a procedure where I can test how well my model is forecasting (comparison between real overall rating and predicted rating).

Comment: the last line of your code gives you predictions on the test set. to access accuracy you should compare these values to actual values in the test set -- e.g. calculate R-squared

Comment: Hello stas, thanks for your quick response. Unfortuantely I don't have an idea how to get this solved. I think first of all I need the original ratings and then the prediction in one table. As a next step I can e.g. calculate some measaures. But how?

Comment: hi @Paul -- looking at your data you can get observations in the test set via `obs_test <- tr.review.asin[6501:7561,]$overall` . regarding the measure see my answer below. plotting your observed vs predicted values can be helpful as well: `plot(obs, mypred)`

Comment: @stasg - I just added the plot to the problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so it completely slipped my attention that you are actually dealing with a classification problem and not with regression. hence a complete edit.

to see how well a classification tree one would want to know how many instances (in the test data) were misclassified, i.e. the assigned class was not the same as the observed class. it is also informative to see how well the prediction model works on each individual class. using `confusionMatrix` function from the `caret` package you can do the following:

```
 install.packages(`caret`)
 library(caret)

 mypred <- predict(model, newdata =test, type = 'class')
 obs <- tr.review.asin[6501:7561,]$overall

 confusionMatrix(obs, mypred)
```

you will get a confusion matrix and some stats as output. confusion matrix tells you on how many instances predictions and observations coincide for each class -- these will be values on the diagonal. in general `ij`th entry of the matrix will tell you how many instances were classified as `j` whilst the real class was `i`.

in the Overall Statistics section of the `confusionMatrix` output you will see Accuracy -- this is the percentage of the instances in the test set that were classified correctly.

next in the Statistics by Class section the row named Pos Pred Value will tell you what percentage of onbservations in class `x` were classified correctly. there is a bunch of other useful statistics that the function outputs and you can read up on it on-line, for example [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/other.html) or [here](http://www.inside-r.org/node/86995).

i hope this helps.

Comment: How can I define `obs`? Any idea?

Comment: @Paul like i said in the comment above, judging from your code: `obs <- tr.review.asin[6501:7561,]$overall` should give you observed values in the test set, however it is difficult to say for sure since you have not posed a sample chunk of your data. perhaps you should consider doing this (using `dput` or otherwise).

Comment: Hi stas, I just added a sample chunk of the input data to my problem description. I am taking just row reviewText and convert it to a corpus. Then I perform some preprocessing steps.

Comment: @Paul you should add sample data in executable format -- unfortunately, a picture of your data is not helpful. also i am not familiar with the format you are using, JSTON. i suggest adding the same chunk in R format (look up on how to use `structure` or `dput`), post preprocessing, i.e. perhaps chunks of `dtmsparse` and `tr.review.asin`. but at any rate, have you tried out my suggestions?

Comment: e.g. post output of `dput(head(dtmsparse))` and `dput(head(tr.review.asin))`.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot post more than 2 links to post the outputs. However I tried to calculate the R-square with your formula. I received the following error messages (rough translation from German to English)
**Warning messages:**
`1: In Ops.factor(obs_test, mypred) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
2: In mean.default(obs_test) :
  argument is neither numerical nor boolean
3: In Ops.factor(obs_test, mean(obs_test)) :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors`

Comment: @Paul apologies i seem to have overlooked the fact that you are dealing with a classification problem: please look at my updated answer. i hope it will be more helpful for you

Comment: @Paul glad it was helpful in the end :)